# Selective routing: how to route the traffic of specific ports through OpenVPN in Ubuntu Server 16.04.4 LTS

Tags: networking, vpn, transmission, routing, plex

My home LAN is organized as follows:

1. DHCP is assigned by a (very) basic modem provided by my ISP (Modem).
2. A server runs Plex Media Server (`uid=plex`, hereinafter: PMS) and Transmission (`uid=debian-transmission`). The OS here is Ubuntu Server 16.04 running headless (no GUI) on my (very) old i5 Sony Vaio (SONY) PC.
3. Media is stored on a NAS (NAS) running some flavor of Linux. Mounting and attributing permissions was not easy, [but I made it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1011337/chmod-gw-not-working-adding-permissions-on-a-nas-to-a-group-using-file-mode/1011573#1011573).
4. [HDHomeRun](https://www.silicondust.com/product/hdhomerun-connect/) streams OTA TV channels to PMS, which redistributes channels both within and without the LAN.
5. A Roku 3 serves as client of PMS and plays media on the big TV in my living room (as it also plays media from my very regular Netflix account, it cannot lie behind a VPN, because Netflix would recognize this and would return an error).
6. In the future, PMS will be acting as a server for IPTV/m3u streams, in accordance with [this guide](https://forums.plex.tv/discussion/83083/rel-iptv-bundle-plug-in-that-plays-iptv-streams-from-a-m3u-playlist). This is not operating now, but will be soon.
7. Transmission sends/receives torrents through `port 20000` and its web interface is active on `port 25000`. Plex operates through `port 30000` and I am planning to direct its inbound IPTV/m3u traffic through `port 35000`,

All works well as long as it lies on the same network and I do not attempt to put anything behind a VPN... which is exactly what I want to do.

In Particular, **I want to direct only the traffic through `ports 20000 and 35000` through the OpenVPN: all the rest should be unaffected.** In particular, the traffic through ports 25000 and 30000 should be unaffected, because it would make it very difficult to operate the server through the web interfaces.

I got myself a nice OpenVPN account and was already able to test it on a `TP-Link TL-WDR4300` flashed with `DD-WRT` (Router).

I am no IT expert, just an aged Linux enthusiast, so I need help and guidance and I spent the last few days studying. I found lots of guides/tutorials on:

1. How to direct **all traffic** through the VPN: however, this is way too much (it would also make my Netflix account unusable);
2. How to direct all traffic of **specific users** through the OpenVpn. Again too much: *ports 25000 and 30000 must remain unaffected* and I want to be able to use the web interfaces;
3. How to put only the SONY behind the TP-Link Router and instruct DD-WRT to do some selective routing of only the traffic directed through **certain ports**.

Item 3. comes closer to what I want to do, but again it seems too much, as it would complicate the architecture, making it difficult for the PMS to dialog with the HDHomeRun. Mounting the NAS onto the SONY and SSHing into the SONY and the NAS would also be negatively affected. And I am very worried that delegating this selective routing to a consumer grade router would end up slowing the connection significantly: the i5 of the SONY, on the other hand, has all the computing power that is needed. And, if possible, I would like to do without the additional Router, for the sake of the energy footprint and to simplify maintenance.

**Is there any solution to tell Ubuntu 16.04 to direct only the traffic of certain ports through OpenVPN? ...or any viable workaround?**

The thing is that I would like something that works automatically, because the system is also operated by my wife and children as end users. I cannot set up different networks and ask them to switch between them depending on what they want to watch on TV or what they need to do. Implementing the solution may be complicated, but using the system should be easy and effortless.

Comment: I am still very interested in this topic. Anyone can help me or point me in the right direction?

Comment: I uninstalled Transmission and Installed `Deluge` instead, that provides setting for `Socks5`: this was not possible with Transmission. I also forced encryption. This may not be ideal, but is a great improvement compared to previous situation and ends up making me sleap better at night. VPN for IPTV streams (addressing specific doors) I wasnt able to do, but most IPTV users report that IPTV providers wont let you stream if behind a VPN, so I guess this is still something I have to figure out. It would be awesome if some power user would come in angelic help.

Comment: This is a much better question for [unix.se], and hsa nothing to do with transmission.